# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor with dtype float and shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

ERROR:

```
self.ss_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.X_shape, name='ss_')  # input Next State
Node: 'ss_'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'ss_' with dtype float and shape [?,30,30,2]
[[{{node ss_}}]]
[[loss/Mean_2/_83]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'ss_' with dtype float and shape [?,30,30,2]
[[{{node ss_}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

```
self.s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.X_shape, name='s')  # input State
self.q_target_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_actions], name='Q_target_1')  
self.s_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.X_shape, name='s_')  # input Next State
self.ss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.X_shape, name='ss')
self.q_target_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_actions], name='Q_target_2') 
self.ss_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=self.X_shape, name='ss_')  # input Next State
self.q_target_total = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_actions], name='q_target_network')
```

```
eval_params_1, eval_output_1  = q_network_1(self.s, 'mainQ_1')
self.q1_eval = eval_output_1
# similarly we build our target Q network
targetQ_params_1, targetQ_output_1 = q_network_1(self.s_, 'targetQ_1')
self.q1_next = targetQ_output_1
eval_params_2, eval_output_2  = q_network_2(self.ss, 'mainQ_2')
self.q2_eval = eval_output_2
# similarly we build our target Q network
targetQ_params_2, targetQ_output_2 = q_network_2(self.ss_, 'targetQ_2')
self.q2_next = targetQ_output_2
mix_eval_params,q_eval_total = mix_network(self.q1_eval,self.q2_eval,'mix_eval')
self.q_eval_total = q_eval_total
mix_target_params,q_target_total = mix_network(self.q1_next,self.q2_next,'mix_target')
self.q_target_total = q_target_total
with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
    self.loss_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.q_target_1, self.q1_eval, name='TD_error_1'))
self.loss_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.q_target_2, self.q2_eval, name='TD_error_2'))
self.loss_3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.q_target_total, self.q_eval_total, name='TD_error_3'))
with tf.variable_scope('train'):
    self._train_op_1 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss_1)
self._train_op_2 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss_2)
self._train_op_3 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss_3)
```

```
batch_memory = random.sample(self.memory, self.batch_size)
state_uav1_batch = [data[0] for data in batch_memory]
action_uav1_batch = [data[1] for data in batch_memory]
reward_uav1_batch = [data[2] for data in batch_memory]
next_state_uav1_batch = [data[3] for data in batch_memory]

state_uav2_batch = [data[4] for data in batch_memory]
action_uav2_batch = [data[5] for data in batch_memory]
reward_uav2_batch = [data[6] for data in batch_memory]
next_state_uav2_batch = [data[7] for data in batch_memory]

reward_uav1_array = np.array(reward_uav1_batch)
reward_uav2_array = np.array(reward_uav2_batch)
stacked_rewards = np.vstack((reward_uav1_array, reward_uav2_array))
reward_total = np.sum(stacked_rewards, axis=0)
```

```
####dqn_1####
q_uav1_next, q_uav1_eval4next = self.sess.run(
    [self.q1_next, self.q1_eval],
    feed_dict={
        self.s_: next_state_uav1_batch, 
        self.s: next_state_uav1_batch,
    }
)    # next observation
q_uav1_eval = self.sess.run(self.q1_eval, {self.s: state_uav1_batch})
q_uav1_target = q_uav1_eval.copy()
batch_index_1 = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
max_act4next_1 = np.argmax(q_uav1_eval4next, axis=1)        # the action that brings the highest value is evaluated by q_eval
selected_q1_next = q_uav1_next[batch_index_1, max_act4next_1]  # Double DQN, select q_next depending on above actions
q_uav1_target[batch_index_1, action_uav1_batch] = reward_uav1_batch + self.gamma * selected_q1_next
self.cost1 = self.sess.run([self._train_op_1, self.loss_1],
feed_dict={self.s: state_uav1_batch,
self.q_target_1: q_uav1_target})
```

```
#####dqn_2####
q_uav2_next, q_uav2_eval4next = self.sess.run(
    [self.q2_next, self.q2_eval],
    feed_dict={
        self.ss_: next_state_uav2_batch,    # next observation
        self.ss: next_state_uav2_batch}
)    # next observation
q_uav2_eval = self.sess.run(self.q2_eval, {self.ss: state_uav2_batch})
q_uav2_target = q_uav2_eval.copy()
batch_index_2 = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
max_act4next_2 = np.argmax(q_uav2_eval4next, axis=1)        # the action that brings the highest value is evaluated by q_eval
selected_q2_next = q_uav2_next[batch_index_2, max_act4next_2]  # Double DQN, select q_next depending on above actions
q_uav2_target[batch_index_2, action_uav2_batch] = reward_uav2_batch + self.gamma * selected_q2_next
self.cost2 = self.sess.run([self._train_op_2, self.loss_2],
feed_dict={self.ss: state_uav2_batch, self.q_target_2: q_uav2_target})
```

```
q_mix_next, q_mix_eval4next = self.sess.run(
    [self.q_target_total, self.q_eval_total], 
    feed_dict={
        self.s_: next_state_uav1_batch,  # next_state_uav1_batch 
        self.ss_: next_state_uav2_batch,  # next_state_uav2_batch 
        self.s: state_uav1_batch,  # state_uav1_batch 
        self.ss: state_uav2_batch  # state_uav2_batch 
    }
)
q_mix_eval = self.sess.run(
    self.q_eval_total,
    feed_dict={self.s: state_uav1_batch, self.ss: state_uav2_batch}
)
q_mix_target = q_mix_eval.copy()
batch_index_3 = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
max_act4next_3 = np.argmax(q_mix_eval4next, axis=1)  
selected_qmix_next = q_mix_next[batch_index_3, max_act4next_3] 
q_mix_target[batch_index_3, max_act4next_3] = reward_total + self.gamma * selected_qmix_next
self.cost_mix = self.sess.run([self._train_op_3, self.loss_3],feed_dict={self.s: state_uav1_batch,self.ss: state_uav2_batch,self.q_target_total: q_mix_target})
```

```
print("s：",np.array(state_uav1_batch).shape)
print("s_：",np.array(next_state_uav1_batch).shape)
print("ss：",np.array(state_uav2_batch).shape)
print("ss_：",np.array(next_state_uav2_batch).shape)
s： (128, 30, 30, 2)
s_： (128, 30, 30, 2)
ss： (128, 30, 30, 2)
ss_： (128, 30, 30, 2)
```

these are right, so how can I do?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).